# Regex to Ignore String With Repeating Pounds (#)

Tags: regex

I need a regex which works as below.

Input String:

```
####
####white-space    
Test#
Test#white-space
```

Output:

```
####               - invalid
####white-space    - invalid
Test###            - invalid
Test-Test###white-space - invalid
Test-Test#         - valid
Test#white-space   - valid
```

The regex should match a string which ends with # or #[:space] or #white-space but it should not match a string which end with repeated #'s or ####white-space.

I have something like this (https://regexr.com/3orvv):

```
^\s*\w*\S*(?:(#)(?!\1))\s?$
```

but it does not work as expected.

Comment: I wrote`^\s*\w*(?:(.)(?!\1))\s?` and its working.

Comment: You might just use [`[^#]#\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/g9baUC/2). If `#` is valid, `(?:^|[^#])#\s*$` can be used.

Comment: @wp78de, `### Test ###` is not valid. so it should not match.

Comment: Another idea: [`^(?:\s*\S*[^#])?#\s?$`](https://regexr.com/3os7u)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood requirement correctly, you may use this regex:

```
^(?!.*#{2}\s*$).*#\s*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gkhGE4/3)

- `(?!.*#{2}\s*$)` is a negative lookahead to assert that we don't have 2 or more `#` followed by optional whitespaces at the end of line.
- `.*#\s*$` matches a `#` followed by 0 or more whitespaces in the end.

Comment: Your regex matches every string except the once with consecutive #'s. I need something which matches a string (including some characters like -, >, <) ending with # or #whitespace and Ignore the string which ends with consecutive #'s at the end. (test###)

Comment: try with some string like "abcd" or "-----" it matches even though it does not end with # or #white-space.

Comment: `test#` is valid since it ends with a single #

Comment: ok got it so single `#` is valid but multiple `#` in the end is invalid?

Comment: yes, that's correct. `test-test# = valid , test# = valid , test#[space] = valid , test-test#[space] = valid , test-test## = invalid, test## = invalid, test##[space] = invalid , test-test##[space] = invalid`.